# Dalvik Memory Allocation - How to change the default limits?

Tags: android

I am currently considering to develop an application for processing of
images captured by the camera of mobile phones using the Android OS.
Before I make the decision to go forth, I have done some research and
found out there are some complaints regarding the limits of the memory
allocated by the Dalvik VM, which seem to be limiting to applications
that require manipulation and processing of images.
Which limits should i have in mind if i would have to process for
example 3 photos taken with the camera, in my process, applying
filters, transforms and other types of mathematical operations?

I would like to know if it is possible to change the default value of
memory allocated by the Dalvik VM for each application (this default
is of 16 MB), in any way, using the Android 1.6 OS. Has anybody looked
into this that can help me out please?

I have also read in the Android 2.1 compatibility definition document
(available here:
http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/pt-PT//compatibility/android-2.1-cdd.pdf
)
that it is possible to change the allocation of memory by the Dalvik
VM from 16 MB to 24 MB or even a bigger amount if it is necessary, but
it is not mentioned anywhere how this can be done.

If someone has looked into those issues before and could give me some
help or hints, it would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: btw: on Nexus One the default heap size is already at 24 MB per app

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a usual device you cannot change the heap-limits of your application. They are hardcoded by the OEM. If you are developing for some device of which you have full control, you can modify Dalvik startup scripts to allow more heap space.

Comment: Do you have information on how to modify Dalvik startup scripts regarding higher default heap size per app? Does the phone need to be rooted for that? I'm developing an app that will be bundled/distributed together with a device, where I'd be in full control, not rooted (yet) though.

Comment: you need to have a complete access to the phone, modifying startup scripts means a root acceess.
in case u have a root access - edit init script (it's in root /init.rc)
and look for 
"setprop ro.FOREGROUND_APP_MEM 1536 "

Comment: For Dalvik's managed heap limit, you want to edit vendor/[company]/[product]/system.prop and add or update "dalvik.vm.heapsize=24m".  This ends up in /system/build.prop, and eventually turns into a -Xmx argument.

Answer (score 2):

You may change this by changing `vm.heapSize` item in the avd's config.ini. For example, you may write

```
vm.heapSize=64
```

in config.ini. If there is no such item, you may add a new one.

However, please notice that `vm.heapSize` may be overridden by the skin. There is a `hardware.ini` in the skin's path, and it contains default settings of `vm.heapSize` and `hw.ramSize` which may override your value. To workaround this problem, you may set

```
skin.path=720x1280
skin.name=720x1280
```

The numbers are not important, it must be in the (width)x(height) form.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the default global heap size via adb shell setprop, for instance:

```
   setprop dalvik.vm.heapsize 128m
```