# Custom Heap Size in Android Platform?

Tags: android, embedded, porting, heap-memory

The software team in our graduation project asked for increasing the heap size per process in Android. They said that the default is "16MB" which isn't sufficient for them.
How could I custom the size?

I found a commented line in the file: `/acme/my_board/BoardConfig.mk` in my android source code:

```
# USE_CUSTOM_RUNTIME_HEAP_MAX := "64M"
```

Is that what I need to edit??

Comment: Is this for the default heap for any application, so you want to change it with custom build of the OS or is the goal to change the heap size at runtime of a particular application?

Comment: Well, any of them will solve my problem. However, the second option "for specific" is much better.

Comment: This question kinda relates with a question I asked before on this issue, which you can check over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078301/dalvik-memory-allocation-how-to-change-the-default-limits
According to the answers, you have to change the OS build, and the instructions posted in the answers should do the thing, even though I did not get to try them myself, for I was seeking a solution application-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got that answer through android-platform mailing list

> You can change *[`platform/dalvik/vm/Init.c`](http://review.omapzoom.org/#patch,sidebyside,4578,1,vm/Init.c)*
>
> For example to make it 32MB, you can do below
>
> *`gDvm.heapSizeMax = 32 * 1024 * 1024;`*
>
> Another suggested approach is to update your *[`system.prop`](http://review.omapzoom.org/#patch,sidebyside,4927,1,system.prop)*
>
> Regards,
>   Muthu Subramaniam

Answer (score 3):

In your onCreate method in your activity, or, if you want it for all your applications in a package, a custom Application object's onCreate, add

```
dalvik.system.VMRuntime.getRuntime().setMinimumHeapSize(yournumberhere);
```

Edit: Also note that Android will automatically increase the heap size if it needs more. So even though the default might be 16, if it needs more, it will increase it. However that might make a little hickup in a real-time situation which is bad. Therefore if you know it will go over 16 it's good to do it before-hand.

Comment: It's also worthwhile to note that this isn't a sustainable method for increasing an application heap size, refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/VMRuntime.html ... This class is deprecated.
this is an internal Dalvik class that is not appropriate for general use. It will be removed from the public API in a future release.