# Android: use up tons of RAM?

Tags: android, memory-management

I'm looking to somehow enable access for my app to use up practically all  the device's RAM. This app I am creating is not designed for general release, it is just a personal project, but it requires a ton (~128mb) of RAM. My Nexus One has 512MB of RAM, but yet I cannot allocate more then ~10MB of RAM max. How can I let my app allocate as much as it wants?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know you wont be able to change the Memory allocation values from code using API calls. It needs to be changed on the Android source and you might need to compile and create your own custom ROM

FYI...

This is a post containing a similar kind of issue

[Dalvik Memory Allocation - How to change the default limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078301/dalvik-memory-allocation-how-to-change-the-default-limits)