# OutOfMemory error even though Large bitmaps are handled efficiently

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, out-of-memory, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I'm developing a tour guide application. I'm using a flipper view for images. I have decoded bitmaps. But it still gives the outofmemoryError. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.isuru.allaboutkataragama/com.isuru.allaboutkataragama.Thissa}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error
>   inflating class
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at 
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-01 10:30:47.595:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(30992): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:361)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1956)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   com.isuru.allaboutkataragama.Thissa.onCreate(Thissa.java:83)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992): Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992): Caused by:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at 
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
>
> 09-01 10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):  at
>   android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:131) 09-01
>   10:30:47.595: E/AndroidRuntime(30992):    at
>   android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:121)

This my code.

```
iv1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgvw_thissa1);
        iv2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgvw_thissa2);
        iv3=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgvw_thissa3);
        iv4=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgvw_thissa4);
        iv5=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgvw_thissa_lake);

        iv1.setImageBitmap(
                decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tissamaharama, 400, 400));

        iv2.setImageBitmap(
                decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.thissa2, 275, 183));

        iv3.setImageBitmap(
                decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.thissa3, 400, 400));

        iv4.setImageBitmap(
                decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.thissa7, 400, 400));

        iv5.setImageBitmap(
                decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.thissalake, 400, 400));



    public static int calculateInSampleSize(  
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {  
    // Raw height and width of image  
    final int height = options.outHeight;  
    final int width = options.outWidth;  
    int inSampleSize = 1;  

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {  
        if (width > height) {  
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);  
        } else {  
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);  
        }  
    }  
    return inSampleSize;  
}  


    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }
```

Comment: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class` problem with your xml file too.

Answer (score 0):

When you get out of memory in java, you must ensure heap size firstly. You must expand memory usage of VM:

```
java -Xmx2048m -Xms256m
```

It means that your application will start with 256 MB storage and then it can raise to 2048 maximumly. You must use multiple of 2 for defining memory value.

You can also define memory with different unit(kilobyte, megabyte and gigabyte respectively):

```
-Xmx1024k
-Xmx512m
-Xmx1g
```

In Android, you can do it like in below link:

[Dalvik Memory Allocation - How to change the default limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078301/dalvik-memory-allocation-how-to-change-the-default-limits)

Comment: Where should I define this 
java -Xmx2048m -Xms256m

Comment: You can look at link which i shared now. You can search more for Dalvik VM setting.